# How to solve Navbar overlap with body content or other page in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a navigation bar with CSS and JS. The picture below show my example of nav bar
[image: My Example JS]

The problem is, when i choose type "MY ACCOUNT" it will display some content. Then if i hover mouse on "Value Graph" it give me result of overlapping with body content of My Account. Here is the problem.

[image: My Problem Navbar]

Here is my CSS For Navbar

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,600);

@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

/* minimal styles for that navi */
.rmm {margin: 0 auto;}
.rmm ul {margin: 0; padding:0; list-style: none; position: relative; 
background: #000;}
.rmm ul:after {content: ""; clear: both; display: block;}
.rmm ul li {float: left;}
.rmm ul li:hover {background: #202020;}
.rmm ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
.rmm ul li:hover a{color: #fff;}
.rmm ul li a {color: #fff; display: block; text-decoration: none;}
.rmm ul ul {display: none; margin:0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 
100%;}
.rmm ul ul li {float: none; position: relative;}
.rmm ul ul li a{color: #fff;}
.rmm ul ul li a:hover {background: #202020;}
.rmm ul ul ul {position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0; width: 100%;}

/* mobile menu header button */
.rmm-toggled {width: 100%; background-color: #555555; min-height: 50px; 
margin: 0 auto; display: none;}
.rmm-closed ~ .rmm-mobile {display: none!important;}
.rmm-toggled-controls{width: 100%;}
.rmm-toggled-title{width: 60%; float: left; font-size: 27px; color: #fff; 
font-weight:600; display: block; padding: 8px 0; text-decoration: none; 
text-transform: uppercase; text-align: left; padding-left: 35px;}
.rmm-toggled-button{width: 20%; float: left; margin-top: 3px;
 display:block;
width: 32px;
padding:0 !important;
margin:10px 10px 0 0;
border:1px solid #fff;
border-radius:3px;
float: right;
}
.rmm-toggled-button span{float: left; display:block; margin: 3px 6px; 
height: 3px; background:white; width:20px;}

/* normalny back button visible only on mobiles  */
.rmm .rmm-back{display: none; font-size: 12px;}
.rmm .rmm-back:after {display: none;}
.rmm .rmm-back a:after {
font-family: 'icomoon';
speak: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
content: "\e000";
 position: relative;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
transform: rotate(-60deg);
top: 1px;
 right: -2px ;
float: left;
font-size: 10px;
}
.rmm-mobile .rmm-back{display: block;}

  /* mobile menu list */
  .rmm-mobile{width: 100%;}
  .rmm-mobile .rmm-dropdown:hover ~ ul, .rmm-mobile .rmm-dropdown:hover > ul 
  ,.rmm-mobile .rmm-dropdown:hover + ul {display: none!important;}
   .rmm-mobile ul{width: 100%; position: inherit!important;}
   .rmm-mobile li{width: 100%; }

   /* mobile menu js action */
  .rmm-dropdown{display: block!important;}
  .rmm-mobile .rmm-subview{display: block!important; width: 100%;}
  .rmm-mobile .rmm-subover-hidden{display: none!important;}
  .rmm-mobile .rmm-subover-visible{display: block;}
  .rmm-mobile .rmm-subover-header{display: none!important; padding: 0; 
   margin:0;}

  /* mobile menu content */
  .rmm-mobile .rmm-submenu{position: relative; left: 0px;}

  .rmm .rmm-mobile li:hover > ul {display: none;}

  /* arrow down for wide screen */
  .rmm.style {text-align: left; font-family: Tahoma;}
  .rmm.style ul {box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
   background:#990; 
   text-transform: uppercase; display: inline-table; text-align:left;}
  .rmm.style ul li {text-align:left;}
  .rmm.style ul li:hover {background: #4b545f;}
  .rmm.style ul ul {display: none; margin:0; background: #5f6975; border-
   radius: 0px; padding: 0; position: absolute;}
  .rmm.style ul li a {color: #fff; font-weight:600; display: block; padding: 
   15px 35px; text-decoration: none; font-weight:600; }
  .rmm.style ul ul li {border-bottom: 1px solid #575F6A; border-top: 1px 
   solid #6B727C;}
  .rmm.style ul ul li a {padding: 12px 35px; color: #fff; }
  .rmm.style ul ul li a:hover {background: #4b545f;}

   /* arrow down for wide screen */
   .rmm.style ul li > a:not(:only-child):after {
   font-family: 'icomoon';
   speak: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   content: "\e000";
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
    transform: rotate(210deg);
    top: -4px;
    left: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
   }

   /* arrow left for wide screen submenus  */
   .rmm.style ul ul li > a:not(:only-child):after {-webkit-transform: 
    rotate(120deg)!important; transform: rotate(120deg)!important; top: 2px; 
   font-size: 14px; float: right; margin-right: -20px;}

    /* mobile style */
   .rmm.style .rmm-mobile li > a:not(:only-child):after {-webkit-transform: 
     rotate(120deg)!important; transform: rotate(120deg)!important; top: 
     4px!important; font-size: 14px!important; float: right; margin-right: 
    -20px;}
    .rmm.style .rmm-mobile li{background: #3ab4a6; border-bottom: 1px solid 
    #575f6a!important; border-top: 0!important; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to give `z-index` in your navigation

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: THANKYOU for your suggestion. I have added z-index on my Navbar css. It  works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `z-index` on my css. Here is the answer:

```
/* arrow down for wide screen */

.rmm.style {text-align:center; font-family: Tahoma; }
.rmm.style ul {box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); background-color: #F8F8F8; 
text-transform: uppercase; display: inline-table; text-
align:left; z-index: 1; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nirav Joshi for your helped